# Current company extended notice period and told me when I resigned

Tags: resignation, job-change, negotiation, india, notice-period

I have been working in this company (Indian IT Service Based Company) since last two years. When I joined, I was told that notice period is of one month.

My colleagues were subject to the same when they resigned last year, they were full time working employees.

Through these two years, I have received offer letter, appraisal and other kind of documents from the company. Nowhere the company has ever mentioned about the notice period.
Neither did company ever notified me about the notice period or its extension by any medium.

I remember, last year I resigned as well. They never informed back then either that notice period is extended to two months. Offer was covered by  the company so I didn' leave.

Last day, I resigned and now they are saying that notice period for full time employees is of two months and for intern/trainee it is one month.

I have already accepted offer from another company to whom I notified I would join after one month.

What could I possibly do here?

Comment: What does the law say?

Comment: The labor laws in your country/city. Is a notice period required by law? Is the notice period in writing? If so, is it legally binding? Can the company legally change the notice period after you've accepted employment? These are all questions I would be seeking the answers to.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is not for you to answer these questions but for you to seek the answers from a person who knows and understands the labor laws in your country, such as an attorney.

Comment: When you joined the notice period was a month. The company says that for interns/trainees the notice period is a month. The obvious question is, did you start as a trainee, and now you are no longer a trainee?

Comment: There needs to be a Stack just for Indian Employment and Contract issues - as they seem to be unique.

Comment: Inform your new employer immediately. Show them proof showing your side. Don't just tell HR of the new company, tell the hiring manager as well, by email them both, and immediately calling them. If they're willing take your side and back you up, then you won't need your relieving letter (which I understand is a thing in India) from your current employer.

Comment: I'd start by asking your employer to show you exactly where in your employment contract it says what your notice period is.

Comment: "What could I possibly do here?"  Seek legal counsel.

Comment: And ask the other questions: What can they do if you just quit and don't show up for the second month? What can they do to you? Or what would happen if you throw a chair through the window and scream at the boss that you can't take working there any more? What could you so that they would fire you? Notice periods are always just a courtesy.

Comment: *I remember, last year I resigned as well.* What happened then? Did they rehire you, with a new contract, which might have a different notice period?

Comment: The pre-edit version was a bit wordy, but cutting it down to just two sentences is absurd. I can easily see people VTC on the current version.

Comment: @DavidR "Notice periods are always just a courtesy." No, violating them can be breach of contract and give rise to a civil suit. And depending on the country, there may be further consequences. In India, getting a new job while not leaving your previous employer on good terms can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll be honest, India's employment laws are a bit of a shambles. We hear horror stories come out of India all the time. It seems the company can just withhold a relieving letter at a whim.

Unless you have very solid proof that the notice period is meant to be a month I would assume it's a lost cause and work the two months.

Unless you can get some sort of written documentation detailing that the notice period has been changed, I doubt it's even worth considering pushing back.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari the point is it doesn't matter if it's legal or not, companies are allowed to get away with these shenanigans on a regular basis. Laws only matter if they're enforced.

Comment: You could have a scenario where they are wrong about being able to change notice period. However they can decide to simply drag their feet on a relieving letter. You really need someone that understands indian employment law to advise you - both on paper and off paper. I've had an Indian colleague tell me before that you simply go to the persons office who hands out relieving letters and yell at them daily non stop until they give you one. So all in all I think people on this forum aren't that qualified to help. Including me

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari: Can they? Well, they did, so they can. Is it legal? Quite possibly not. Can you do anything about it? Here in the UK, my employment lawyer would just laugh about them and make them pay. In India, where you are, for all I know there's very little you can do, other than staying two months, or talking to a got employment lawyer.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari - just get a lawyer.  It's not that expensive.

Comment: @Fattie I wasn't aware you knew how expensive lawyers are in India.

Comment: hi @GregoryCurrie !  I'm sorry, I don't follow you ?

Comment: @Fattie You caught me off guard. I wouldn't have thought you knew how expensive lawyers are in India, but you've told us they are cheap. That's really interesting.

Comment: ah I probably mentioned .. I lived and did business there for some yrs. !

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, lawyers are cheap compared to the cost of damage they can prevent. Everywhere. If a lawyer costs you two days salary, that's cheap compared to one month notice period that you don't want to work.

Comment: @gnasher729 fully agree. Lawyering up ASAP is cheaper than lawyering up later or not at all

Answer (score -2):

> What could I possibly do here?

The most helpful answer here would be to get a lawyer. They will have way better ways of helping you than we have, and even if we had perfect information, a lawyers letterhead on a letter is always more powerful in a negotiation than a private person having read something on the internet.

---

That said, let me dig a little deeper here. We get a lot of questions from India that amaze the people here, because Indian labor laws seem to be so impractical and unfair to employees. But you are a democracy. There are way more employees in your country than employers. So why do you have these amazingly bad laws?

You said yourself, you don't even know what the law is. You are unsure, if in a working contract one party can single-handedly change facts without your acceptance and/or signature. That would not even be a question where I live. Every professional education here includes a part about labor law. And while it's boring and many people decide to forget the details as soon as they passed the exam, it's their choice. They were educated. They were informed. They can look up more information on their own now to stay informed and make valid choices of their own.

I am sure Indian labor laws have a long history of things that happened before you were born. But to quote a favorite punk rock band of mine: "It's not your fault that the world is what it is, it's only your fault if it stays that way."

If you want to live in a country with good labor laws, where you don't have to ask questions like this, the first step is to get educated about your own laws. And then vote for a party that makes better labor laws.

As long as you actively don't care about your labor laws, your laws will always be of the same quality as if you bought sausage and actively don't care what the  ingredients are.

Comment: In the USA there is no law that requires an employer to pay vacation leave–how crazy is that? To a European US employees enjoy very limited rights: they can be fired on a whim, a boss can promote a less skilled, less experienced worker because they can; the minimum wage can be as low as $8. When people lose their jobs, for whatever reason, in many cases they cannot claim unemployment benefit. Yet, the US is a democratic nation, and a republic too, whose Declaration of Independence states "that all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights"...

Comment: `And then elect a party that makes better labor laws.` such a sanctimonious answer, what do you know about India and how things are run there and what people have to face?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your US comment. I am told time and again that US citizens *like* those freedoms they have with next to zero labor laws. Anybody who does not, needs to vote for a candidate who improves them. For the US I guess that would be people around AOC right now. Or Bernie. That is democracy, right?

Comment: "what do you know about India and how things are run there and what people have to face?" I know they are a democratic country and while the expats here always follow the elections with interest, they never told any stories about being actively hindered to vote or being afraid to go voting. The only thing that will *guarantee* you don't get your will when voting is not being informed enough to actually make a valid choice on the ballot.

Comment: Somehow you suggested it is the OP's fault if their boss(es) lied and/or failed to communicate the most basic fundamental regulations in their contract, i.e. how many weeks/months notice period an employee has to give. How does that help?

Comment: I really don't know much about Indian democracy, but I would seem it's largely irrelevant to the question. Opining about democracy is likely to generate more heat rather than light. I also want to throw it out there that contracts can often override statutory minimums.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I never did that. Please quote me. I have no idea whether their boss lied and I made no assumption about that, neither did I say or imply their bosses alleged actions were in any way the OPs fault. I'm saying their labor laws are crappy and not being educated enough about them to judge this situation for themselves means that the laws will not improve even though it's a democracy. Democracy *at a minimum* needs educated citizens to work correctly.

Comment: "For the US I guess that would be people around AOC right now. Or Bernie. That is democracy, right?" LOL ok, that tells me enough about you.  Are you gainfully employed?

Comment: @Jack Thankfully, not in the US. But yes, I am. In a country with strong labor laws, proper labor law education and the choice between at least 5-7 democratic parties, at least 3 of which would improve our current labor laws. Whether that is a priority over other issues when I cast my vote is my private secret, but I feel confident that I can make that informed choice for myself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "In the USA there is no law that requires an employer to pay vacation leave–how crazy is that?" Umm, not at all. "a boss can promote a less skilled, less experienced worker because they can" Does Europe have laws against that? If so, that means that who is "qualified" is not determined by actual business people, but by government bureaucrats. "When people lose their jobs, for whatever reason, in many cases they cannot claim unemployment benefit." Only for rather small values of "many".

Comment: @nvoigt "I am told time and again that US citizens like those freedoms they have with next to zero labor laws." We don't have "next to zero labor laws". We have LOTS of labor laws. In some states, one of those labor laws is that people can't be fired for not getting COVID vaccines. That's what happens when you let employment decisions be decided by "democracy". Hooray for socialism! "not being educated enough about them to judge this situation for themselves means that the laws will not improve" So it's because of their actions. That sure sounds like blame to me.

Comment: "The only thing that will guarantee you don't get your will when voting is not being informed enough to actually make a valid choice on the ballot." ??? If enough people vote against what you're voting for, then you won't get what you're voting for.

Comment: "We have LOTS of labor laws" Well, maybe compared to North Korea. Compared to Europe, not so much. And I get it, you cannot have any meaningful labor laws or worker protections when you want to keep the freedom to fire anybody you want for any reason you want. But that is a choice. That's not a law of nature. You *could* come up with better worker protection. But as a country you collectively don't want to.

Comment: "If enough people vote against what you're voting for, then you won't get what you're voting for." if you parse my sentence from English into logic, you will find that your sentence and mine do not contradict each other.